# open source project about implementing WebRTC MCU on the server

Tags: open-source, webrtc

I have recently study on how to implement WebRTC MCU software on the server. I find an open source project called [licode](http://lynckia.com/licode/), but it is difficult for me to understand its source code. Can you recommmend some articles or documents about explaining the source code of licode, or there is another open source project you can recommend about implementing WebRTC MCU?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Janus**](http://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) is what you are looking for. It is the new cool kid on the block and I've found it to be really easy to understand since it doesn't make assumptions in the signaling plane or the features you'll use in your gateway.

It comes with a core that acts as a central hub for browser connections and then implements all its features with plugins. For instance here you have the Video MCU plugin code:

https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/blob/master/plugins/janus_videoroom.c

As you can see it is programmed in C and comes with a JS API and clear code samples. Give it a go, I think it is ideal for a project study compared to already bloated multi-stack solutions (Licode, Jitsi Videobridge, etc)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nowadays, Janus videoroom is an SFU, so this answer seems inaccurate. Example MCU: [OpenVCX](http://openvcx.com/vcxwebrtc.php)

Comment: That website is down, did the project die?